# how to allow inserts with isolation level serialization

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that is used by multiple threads. My requirement is that I do not want any other user to insert any row between the range that I specify. However when applying (holdlock) hint sql server is putting lock on the whole table.
My query is

```
 begin transaction
    select id,firstname,lastname from dbo.emptable with (holdlock)    
    where id between 1 and 3
```

-- Here I do not want any other user to insert or update and record between id 1 and 3. However I am now not allowed to insert any row from another session. If i try to insert a row it is been blocked. Even if i try to update a row with ID = 4 still it is blocked.
The table has clustered index on id column and nonclustered index on columns firstname,lastname.

Comment: Have you tried using `ROWLOCK`? AFAIK `HOLDLOCK` is a table-level kind of locking so in your case, the whole table will be locked.

Comment: You mention insert row between 1 and 3 should be blocked. I understand that you wish to block non existing row?

Comment: I want to block rows 1 , 2 and 3. No user should be allowed to insert or update these rows

Answer (score 0):

A table with 2 columns; [id] and [value]. The [id] column is of type INT and [value] can be 356366. I could prevent a user from inserting a row with an [id] between 1 and 3 using something like

```
DECLARE @id INT = 1

INSERT INTO dbo.Table_1 (
id
,value
)
SELECT TOP 1 @id
,356366
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE @id NOT BETWEEN 1
    AND 3
```

Or, prevent them from updating with something like

```
DECLARE @id INT = 1

UPDATE dbo.Table_1
SET [value] = 356366
WHERE id = @id
AND @id NOT BETWEEN 1
    AND 3
```